# how to install stormcloud from source?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install the weather app Stormcloud from the source on GitHub (found here)

https://github.com/consindo/stormcloud

I downloaded the zip file and opened the README file inside it. It told me to download node-webkit and to drag stormcloud to node-webkit. I don't understand what it is asking me to do. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download prebuilt [Node Webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit#downloads) binaries.

Download the zip file from https://github.com/consindo/stormcloud and extract it.

Now open a terminal and enter the following command:

```bsh
path/to/nw path/to/stormcloud
```

(You will need to change them according to the file locations.)

You can make a .desktop file to associate Stormcloud with its icon and use the Unity launcher count feature.